# Pie Chart Drawing in Android

Tags: android

This is the code I have used for the chart - it is not displaying properly:

```
RectF rectf = new RectF (10, 10, 200, 200);
Paint paint = new Paint();

for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
    canvas.drawArc(rectf, 0, list_degree[i], true, paint);
  } else {
    paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
    canvas.drawArc(rectf, (list_degree[i-1]), (list_degree[i]), true, paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: need more explanation on what you're trying to do specifically and what you have tried...

Comment: "it is not displaying properly:" - does not constitute a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try some charting libraries which will give you a Nice look of Charts something like achartengine,flot graph etc

Comment: The pie chart covers only half the area and the shaded portions of the respective values provided do not match the percent of area they should cover. Surely some error in the calculation part which i couldn figure.

Comment: @user755050: I tried using those libraries, dint work out that well for me. It always gives me the force close option. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Can you post me the log cat raised during that error time so that i can proceed further

Comment: I got it right, as i had mentioned, the logic was wrong. The correct code would be, for(int i=0;i<values2.length;i++)
   {
    if(i==0)
    {
     paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
     canvas.drawArc(rectf, 0,value_degree[i], true, paint);
     
    }
    else
    {
     temp+=(int) value_degree[i-1];
     paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
     canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
    }
   }